# Getting Discrepancy in OC4J server - Spring-framework 3.0.1.RELEASE jar and commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Tags: java, spring-bean, apache-commons-logging, oc4j

Using Spring-framework 3.0.1.RELEASE jar and added commons-logging-1.1.1.jar but still I m getting the below error,
when try to deploy in OC4J 10.1.3 version server

Added the required jar to server.xml but still only commons-logging-1.1.1.jar jar is not getting recognised by the server.

```
from server
Operation failed with error: Missing class: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory Dependent class: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils Loader: org.springframework:3.1.0 Code 



  Source: /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_server/springframework/spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar Configuration: in /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_server/j2ee/home/config/server.xml This load was initiated at org.springframework:3.1.0 using the loadClass() method. The missing class is available from the following locations: 1. Code-Source: /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_server/j2ee/home/applications/tool/myapplication-0.0.2/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar () This code-source is not in use by any loader. 2. Code-Source: /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_server/org/apache/commons/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar (from in /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_server/j2ee/home/config/server.xml) This code-source is available in loader apache.commons.logging:1.1.1. 

    Caused by: oracle.classloader.util.AnnotatedClassNotFoundException:

              Missing class: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

            Dependent class: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils
                     Loader: org.springframework:3.1.0
                Code-Source: /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_server/springframework/spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
              Configuration: <code-source> in /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_server/j2ee/home/config/server.xml

    This load was initiated at org.springframework:3.1.0 using the loadClass() method.


    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    From server log

    The missing class is available from the following locations:

            1. Code-Source: /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_server/j2ee/home/applications/app/apppoc-0.0.2/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar ()
               This code-source is not in use by any loader.

            2. Code-Source: /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_server/org/apache/commons/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar (from <code-source> in /C:/Users/II/Documents/oc4j_server/oc4j_extended_1013
               This code-source is available in loader apache.commons.logging:1.1.1.

            at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.handleClassNotFound(PolicyClassLoader.java:2204)
            at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.internalLoadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:1726)
            at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:1682)
            at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:1667)
            ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing server.xml and introducing the commons logging. Could you try adding commons.logging as a shared library via the EM Console and then refer to it in orion-application.xml i.e. assuming you have named it "apache.commons.logging"

```
<imported-shared-libraries> 
            <import-shared-library name="apache.commons.logging"/> 
 </imported-shared-libraries>
```